# using FOR, how do I check filename for a word before action if negative while keeping it simple?

Tags: batch-file

This searches and counts video episodes with a `%string%` variable that reads like `A?Title?of?Show?S` (where the S is the beginning of the season#/episode# tag).

```
 set count=0
 for /f "delims=" %%i in ('where ".:%string%*"') do set /a count+=1
```

My problem is that I want to count total different episodes, not same ones.
Episodes are wildly differently named with certain similarities like the episode tag. I need the `where` command to also find episodes with dots as spaces:

```
The.Show.S01E01.Pilot.1080p.mp4
Another Show S10E19 Untitled.mkv
Another_Show_S10E19.m4v
```

This list should return a `%count%` of `1` for series `Another Show`. I have a script `getname.cmd` to call that turns filenames into variables like the episode tag into `%episode%` variable that reads like `S01E01`.

Hopefully this doesn't blow the complexity out of proportion.

----- edit: my solution

I think the solution will probably be something like this...

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set count=1
echo. >%temp%\get_ep.txt
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('where ".:%string%*" 2^>nul') do (
    call getname.cmd "%%i" data
    echo %episode% >>%temp%\get_ep.txt
    type "%temp%\get_ep" | find /i "%episode%" >nul
    if "%errorlevel%"=="1" set /a count+=1
    )
endlocal & set count=%count%
```

however this doesn't work because the variables are not carried over from getname.cmd for some reason. I'm probably using delayedexpansion wrong..?

Comment: So you're just counting the number of episodes of a particular series?

Comment: yes exactly, number of different episodes

Comment: If the filenames already contain a `S##E##'` pattern you are IMO better off with a script language with complete RegEx features like vbscript or Powershell to exclude dupe episodes.

Comment: You **must** post a small list of filenames, with and without "duplicates", and the output you want from such a list. It is very hard to guess what you really want from the current description... Why do you use `where` command? Can not the same result be obtained via `dir /B` or a plain `for` command?

Comment: So for `Another Show`, if there is `S01E01` and `S02E01`, the result is `2` episodes, right? What are the exact criteria to find equally-titled series (separator characters _space_, `_`, `.`, or are there even more)?

Comment: 2 would be correct. no other separators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out about `||` that is used to execute when previous command fails, making this all too easy. I can't believe I only now found out about this!

```
set count=1    
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('where ".:%string%*" 2^>nul') do echo "%%~ni" | find /i "%episode%" >nul || set /a count+=1
```

granted, this doesn't check for existing duplicates but only if this new file is a duplicate. this should be good enough, I just have to do a single sweep for duplicates by other means.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a trivial task to accomplish as it is not too simple to extract the season/episode portion `S??E??` from the file names. I would probably do it with a script like this (see the `rem` comments):

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_ROOT=%~dp0."      & rem // (directory containing the files to process)
set "_NUMS=S??E??"      & rem // (pattern that matches season/episode number)
set _SEPS=" " "_" "."   & rem // (quoted list of all permitted separators)
set "_MASK=*%_NUMS%*.*" & rem // (mask that files to be processed must match)
set "_REGEX=%_NUMS:?=[0123456789]%"  & rem // (regular expression for season/episode)
set "_TEMP=%TEMP%\%~n0_%RANDOM%.tmp" & rem // (path to temporary file)
rem set "_TEMP=%~dpn0.tmp"  & rem // (or a temporary file located next to batch file)
set "_NAME=Another Show"& rem // (name of show to determine count of episodes)
rem set /P _NAME="Title of show: "       & rem // (or name of show entered by user)

rem // Write list of `%_NUMS%` occurrences and related names to temporary file:
> "%_TEMP%" (
    rem // Loop through all matching files:
    for /F "delims= eol=|" %%F in ('
        dir /B /A:-D "%_MASK%"
    ') do (
        rem // Store original file name in variable:
        set "FILE=%%~nF "
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        rem // Replace all possible separators by spaces:
        for %%C in (!_SEPS!) do (
            set "FILE=!FILE:%%~C= !"
        )
        rem // Pass modified file names beyond `endlocal`:
        for /F "delims= eol=|" %%E in ("!FILE!") do (
            endlocal
            rem // Store modified file name in variable:
            set "FILE=%%E"
            rem // Initialise flag for finding first `%_NUMS%` occurrence:
            set "FLAG=#"
            setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            rem // Split modified file name by spaces and loop through parts:
            for %%I in ("!FILE: =" "!") do (
                rem // Check flag if no `%_NUMS%` occurrence has yet been found:
                if defined FLAG (
                    endlocal
                    rem // Store current part of file name:
                    set "ITEM=%%~I"
                    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
                    rem // Check part of file name against regular expression:
                    echo/"!ITEM!"| > nul findstr /R /X /C:^"\"%_REGEX%\"^" && (
                        rem // Match found, so extract file name before part:
                        for /F "delims=| eol=|" %%J in ("!FILE: %%~I =|!") do (
                            endlocal
                            set "NAME=%%J"
                            set "FLAG="
                            setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
                        )
                        rem // Output `%_NUMS%` occurrence and file name before:
                        echo/!ITEM!^|!NAME!
                    )
                )
            )
        )
        endlocal
    )
)

rem // Clean up variables beginning with `#`:
for /F "delims==" %%K in ('set "#" 2^> nul') do set "%%K="
rem // Search temporary file for certain name:
for /F "tokens=1* delims=| eol=|" %%K in ('
    findstr /L /I /E /C:"|%_NAME%" "%_TEMP%"
') do (
    rem // Assign each found name to variable beginning with `#`:
    set "#%%K=%%L"
)
rem // Count number of variables beginning with `#`:
for /F %%C in ('set "#" ^| find /C /V ""') do set "COUNT=%%C"
rem // Return count:
echo/%COUNT%

rem // Clean up temporary file:
del "%_TEMP%"

endlocal
exit /B
```

This approach uses a temporary file that receives the following data, based on your sample files:

> ```cmd
> S01E01|The Show
> S01E19|Another Show
> S01E19|Another Show
> ```

This temporary file is then searched for lines ending with `|` plus the given name of a show (like `Another Show`, for example). Each of the returned lines is split at the `|` character; the left part, so the season/episode portion, is used as the name of an environment variable with `#` prepended, the right part as the respective value. Since there are no duplicate environment variables possible, duplicate lines result in a single variable (like `#S01E19=Another Show`, for instance). The number of variables beginning with `#` are count finally, and so the result represents the number of individual episodes of the given show.

---

There is actually no temporary file needed, it could be done immediately within the first loop structure, when each derived partial file name is compared against the given show, like this:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_ROOT=%~dp0."      & rem // (directory containing the files to process)
set "_NUMS=S??E??"      & rem // (pattern that matches season/episode number)
set _SEPS=" " "_" "."   & rem // (quoted list of all permitted separators)
set "_MASK=*%_NUMS%*.*" & rem // (mask that files to be processed must match)
set "_REGEX=%_NUMS:?=[0123456789]%"  & rem // (regular expression for season/episode)
set "_TEMP=%TEMP%\%~n0_%RANDOM%.tmp" & rem // (path to temporary file)
rem set "_TEMP=%~dpn0.tmp"  & rem // (or a temporary file located next to batch file)
set "_NAME=Another Show"& rem // (name of show to determine count of episodes)
rem set /P _NAME="Title of show: "       & rem // (or name of show entered by user)

rem // Clean up variables beginning with `#`:
for /F "delims==" %%K in ('set "#" 2^> nul') do set "%%K="
rem // Loop through all matching files:
for /F "delims= eol=|" %%F in ('
    dir /B /A:-D "%_MASK%"
') do (
    rem // Store original file name in variable:
    set "FILE=%%~nF "
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    rem // Replace all possible separators by spaces:
    for %%C in (!_SEPS!) do (
        set "FILE=!FILE:%%~C= !"
    )
    rem // Pass modified file names beyond `endlocal`:
    for /F "delims= eol=|" %%E in ("!FILE!") do (
        endlocal
        rem // Store modified file name in variable:
        set "FILE=%%E"
        rem // Initialise flag for finding first `%_NUMS%` occurrence:
        set "FLAG=#"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        rem // Split modified file name by spaces and loop through parts:
        for %%I in ("!FILE: =" "!") do (
            rem // Check flag if no `%_NUMS%` occurrence has yet been found:
            if defined FLAG (
                endlocal
                rem // Store current part of file name:
                set "ITEM=%%~I"
                setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
                rem // Check part of file name against regular expression:
                echo/"!ITEM!"| > nul findstr /R /X /C:^"\"%_REGEX%\"^" && (
                    rem // Match found, so extract file name before part:
                    for /F "delims=| eol=|" %%J in ("!FILE: %%~I =|!") do (
                        endlocal
                        set "NAME=%%J"
                        set "FLAG="
                        rem // Check if partial file name matches given name:
                        if /I "%%J"=="%_NAME%" (
                            rem // Create variable beginning with `#`:
                            set "#%%~I=%%J"
                        )
                        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
    endlocal
)

rem // Count number of variables beginning with `#`:
for /F %%C in ('set "#" ^| find /C /V ""') do set "COUNT=%%C"
rem // Return count:
echo/%COUNT%

endlocal
exit /B
```

The disadvantage of this approach however is (opposed to the one based on a temporary file that allows to easily reuse it for multiple searches when you slightly modify the script), that you need to walk through all matching files and extracting the season/episode portion once for every search.